# Effect of increase in variance on covariance

Tags: statistics, covariance

I have that the covariance between two random variables is negative: $cov(x,y)<0$. Suppose we replace $x$ by an rv, $x'$, that has higher variance but the same expectation (and, also, a negative covariance with $y$). I want to discern the effect this will have on $cov(x,y)$. In my understanding, $cov(x',y)$ should be less, in absolute value terms, than $cov(x,y)$ (and so less negative), because $x'$ is ‘more random’ than $x$, and should thereby have a weaker relationship with $y$. Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: What have you in mind by an increasing variance of a random variable $x$? The variance of every fixed rv $x$ is again fixed. So change of variance can only appear if the rv itself is replaced by another. Well, what other then? Replacing $x$ by $cx$ maybe (where $c$ is a constant)? See for yourself what happens with variance and covariance in those cases.

Comment: @drhab Yes, replacing it by another, which has a higher variance, but same expectation.

Comment: Then e.g. let $x$ have expectation $0$ and try out the cases $2x$ and $-2x$ in order to check what you suspect. In both cases the variance is multiplied with $4$ (so increases). The covariance is multiplied with $2$ and $-2$ respectively.